# Rectify this query

Tags: mysql, sql

Why the query is not working

```
SELECT (sum(`result` = 1)/count(id) * 100) as `abc`,  
case 
  when `abc` > 80 then 'pass'
  when `abc` < 80 then 'fail'
end as `abcd` 
FROM `user_quiz_answers` WHERE `user_quiz_id` = 39
```

**TABLE:**

```
id          int(11)         AUTO_INCREMENT                                  
question_id     int(11)                                             
result      tinyint(1)
```

**ERROR:**

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'abc' in 'field list'
```

I have managed this but not the above one

```
SELECT 
case 
  when (sum(`result` = 1)/count(id) * 100) > 80 then 'pass' 
  when (sum(`result` = 1)/count(id) * 100) < 80 then 'fail' 
end as `abcd` 
FROM `user_quiz_answers` WHERE `user_quiz_id` = 39
```

Comment: @MitchWheat #1054 - Unknown column 'abc' in 'field list'

Comment: Ah - you can't refer to your alias 'abc' in the places you have - you need to replicate that SUM() statement again.

Comment: @halfer actaully most of my questions get closed :_(

Comment: "actaully most of my questions get closed" - there might be a reason for that?

Comment: @WebDeveloper - hopefully in this case you can see how it could be improved - always state what you expect, and always state what you get :)

Comment: @halfer  is there is a performance problem in the second method that i used

Comment: @WebDeveloper - I'd say there's only a performance problem if you experience one! Try it, and if it causes problems in practise, rewrite it then. "Premature optimisation is the root of all evil", or something like that ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you can't use column aliases as column names in the same query.
Something like this would work

```
SELECT
  `abc`,
  case 
    when `abc` > 80 then 'pass'
    when `abc` < 80 then 'fail'
  end as `abcd` 
FROM (
  SELECT (sum(`result` = 1)/count(id) * 100) as `abc`
  FROM `user_quiz_answers` WHERE `user_quiz_id` = 39
) AS sq
```

Other, simpler way to do what you seem to want to do would be:

```
SELECT 
  IF((sum(`result` = 1)/count(id) * 100) > 80, 'pass','fail') as `abcd`
FROM `user_quiz_answers` WHERE `user_quiz_id` = 39
```

Comment: remove , in line 9 . is there is a performance problem in the second method that i used

Comment: I'm not really sure how optimizer handles this. It's simple enough query, that running it in `BENCHMARK()` could answer this question.

Comment: awesome but again the comma in line 2